# App Exchange Lightning ready concept

Tags: appexchange, security-review, lightning-ready

We are planning to submit our app in app exchange and we are currently in security review step. They have asked us to confirm that our app is lightning ready and asked us few screenshots of the app in lightning experience.

This is an integration app where we query SAP webservices and display it in visualforce pages. We used "datatable" to display the data in tabular format.

1. What are the fastest steps to be taken to confirm it is lightning ready?
2. Is it just enough to check whether our app works in lightning environment or should we apply SLDS and modify the UI accordingly??
3. Our's is  an inline visualforce page used in account detail page  with datatable and page block table tags. We would like to know the modifications that has to be done in order to make it lightning ready?
4. Since Pageblock table is not compatible in lightning do we have to modify the entire page?

Comment: I just pinged the AppExchange team to look at this question.

Comment: Have you read this answers to this question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114150/salesforce-lightning-ready-certification

Answer (score 2):

As long as your app's use cases work within Lightning Experience, this is enough for you to obtain the Lightning Ready badge at this point in time. Note that this is a self-certification obtained by raising a Case via the Partner Community.

More information is available in the Partner Community (under the "What you need to know" tab): p.force.com/lightningready

Answer (score 1):

All of the below would be available to the public...

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/08/are-you-ready-for-the-new-lightning-experience.html

> User experience (UX) is one of the most important aspects of this
> initiative — it’s practically in the name: “Lightning Experience”.
> Accordingly, we want to help our partners evolve their applications to
> this new era of UX.
>
> So what does this mean for your existing app? Many apps feature
> customizations, including custom objects, custom buttons, Visualforce
> pages. In preparation for the Lightning Experience release, all
> partners should test their apps to ensure functionality continues
> working properly in the new experience. Partners can also get their
> apps designated as “Lightning Ready”. Apps that are Lightning Ready
> will work in Lightning Experience and offer a more consistent
> experience with other Lightning pages. If your app uses standard
> Salesforce UI, objects, page layouts, but no custom Visualforce pages,
> then you should expect them to display properly in the new Lightning
> Experience with the new look and feel. In general, Visualforce pages
> will work in the new UI, but they should be tested to ensure all
> features are properly supported and functioning correctly.
>
> To earn the Lightning Ready certification, Visualforce pages in apps
> should be updated to offer a more consistent user experience with
> Lightning. To assist in this effort, we are publishing the Lightning
> Design System, which is formal documentation around all the styles
> that make up the Lightning Experience across all form factors. The
> Lightning Design System is available to all, and will be made GA
> through an open-source project on GitHub for Dreamforce. It can be
> used to design apps built on the Salesforce Platform as well as on
> other platforms. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/
>
> To help customers easily identify apps that work in the new
> experience, we are introducing a new “Lightning Ready” sash for apps.
> This sash will indicate what apps have been certified as “Lightning
> Ready” and therefore will work in the new Lightning Experience and
> offer a consistent user experience. If an app isn’t yet supported in
> Lightning Experience, customers can use it in Salesforce Classic
> instead.
>
> You can find detailed instructions on getting Lightning Ready available at [p.force.com/lightningready](http://p.force.com/lightningready)

Presentation:

https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/30000000bwUm/Y6To9GKaWAJeRlbaUReGYz4FHR.xW6xLcwahCgIO7DI

Answer (score 1):

We have recently added our app on the appexchnage which is lightning ready app.
You have to provide the screenshots of the visualforce pages which you developed in Lightning experience.

And test your app in lightning experience if it work without any issue then get the Lightning Ready certificate.

[image]

[image]