# Alternatives to PageBlock Visualforce in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, pageblock

I am using 2 pageBlocks in a visualforce page. One is rerendering other based on the selsctions. I want to convert the whole visualforce page into lightning but not getting the clear idea of how can I convert the pageBlocks in Lightning.
Can anyone tell me how can I do it.? I am using pageBlockSections, tables and buttons inside paeblock.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Select Items"  id="itemgroups"  >
```

```
     <apex:selectList value="{!itemgroup}" multiselect="false" size="1"  id="sellist">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showitems}" rerender="itemslist,table" status="status"/>
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!groups}"/>
            </apex:selectList>


  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
  <apex:actionstatus id="status" startText="Please Wait.." stopText=""/>


  </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

[image: The Inage of VF page]

Comment: The video on being lightning ready shows this exact example. A search would find it. If not I can post link tomorrow

Comment: That would be helpful if you post the link of the video that does the same.

Comment: here is the post with all the links https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175594/app-exchange-lightning-ready-concept/175611#175611

Comment: The may be the video IIRC - https://developer.salesforce.com/events/webinars/migrating-visualforce-pages-lightning